# How do I recover missing partition? (Windows 8 with recovery USB)

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, system-recovery, recovery-disk

I bought a Samsung laptop with Windows 8 preinstalled. After a year I removed Windows 8 and installed Windows 7. Before removing Windows 8, I made a Windows 8 recovery USB.

Now I want to get back my original Windows 8.

When I used the USB, it said `missing recovery partition` or `partition has been deleted`. Can I install Windows 8 from the internet? and if I use my recovery USB will it activate Windows or not? Or is there any other way to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

A recovery USB flash drive cannot be used to install Windows 8 unless this is an OEM PC that came with Windows 8 preinstalled, and you checked the Copy contents from the recovery partition to the recovery drive box.

A created 32-bit recovery USB flash drive can only be created in a 32-bit Windows 8, and used to repair a 32-bit Windows 8.

A created 64-bit recovery USB flash drive can only be created in a 64-bit Windows 8, and used to repair a 64-bit Windows 8.

try next time to just search google.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5132-recovery-drive-create-usb-flash-drive-windows-8-a.html

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there any other way to do this task?

Download Windows 8.1 Enterprise evaluation (90 days) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx

You can reevaluate as often as you need to.

> Plan ahead. Back up your files and settings before installing this evaluation and, if necessary, again prior to the 90-day expiration.
>
> Upon installation, Windows will prompt you to activate. A product key is not required for this software.
>
> You must complete activation before October 31, 2014 to use this evaluation.
>
> Once you activate, you have up to 90 days to use the software. You can track the amount of time you have left by referring to the “watermark” in the lower right corner of the Windows desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 8 comes with OEM Activation 3.0 which stores the product key in the BIOS, you're in luck.

All you need is the correct Windows 8 recovery media discs (usually Windows 8 Single Language Edition) and when you install from the disc, Windows will automatically fetch the product key from the BIOS and activate itself.

However, these recovery media discs might be hard to come by. You'll probably have to call [Samsung Support](https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/usefulsoftware/supportUsefulSwNotebook.do) and ask them to mail you these discs.